# Memory leak with loop-based Seaborn plotting in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, plot, memory-leaks, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I am having some trouble managing memory with a function that is being called while in a Jupyter notebook. This function contains a calculation which does some pairwise data analysis. During the iterative processing, the loop generates some plots and writes to these to disk.

However, even after closing the plot, I seem to be accumulating approximately 40MB/s into RAM.

Here is simplified example which leaks at this rate:

```
for x in combinations(range(m.num_parameters + 1), 2):

    _plot = sns.pairplot(data=m_df, x_vars=[x[0]], y_vars=[x[1]-1], 
                         size=5)
    _plot.savefig(directory+'{}_{}'.format([x[0]], [x[1]-1]))
    sns.plt.clf()
    sns.plt.close()

    # I can even run the following to no avail:
    del(_plot)
```

And for reference, my data structure is something like:

```
m_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(m.parameters)
m_df.columns = m.parameters.keys()
```

I've done a lot of memory profiling inside Jupyter using various methods like mprun, pympler, and so on. The key hint appeared when I simply commented out the plotting routine, like the one in the example above, and noticed that I no longer filled the RAM.

As a note of clarification, none of these plots are being rendered in the notebook as the code snippet above is representative of a module that is imported and fed data to process.

I have also figured out that I can free up memory by manually running garbage collection in the notebook after the routine is complete (or after a keyboard interrupt).

Does anyone have any insight as to why these plot objects do not appear to be properly closing?

Comment: I've noticed this same thing

Comment: possibly this bug: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7270